# Create horizontally stacking div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm creating a website, and am trying to stack 4 div elements side by side (horizontally)

http://i40.tinypic.com/28tkuq8.png

The image above is how it is currently appearing.

And this is how I want it to look: http://i44.tinypic.com/2h3v8ue.png

This is my HTML code I'm using:

```
<div id="linkscontainer" align="center">
    <div id="1">
        <a href="link">1</a>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
        <a href="link">2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="3">
        <a href="link">3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="4">
        <a href="link">4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#linkscontainer {
    marin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 60px;   
}

#1 {
    background-color: #3B5998;
    height: 60px;
    width: 25%;
    font-family: 'Nixie One', cursive;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;      
}

#2 {
    background-color: #00B5B5;
    height: 60px;
    width: 25%;
    font-family: 'Nixie One', cursive;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;      
}

#3 {
    background-color: #F78F10;
    height: 60px;
    width: 25%;
    font-family: 'Nixie One', cursive;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;      
}

#4 {
    background-color: #EF0E11;
    height: 60px;
    width: 25%;
    font-family: 'Nixie One', cursive;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;      
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Use `#1,#2,#3,#4{display:inline-block}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div` is a `block` level element by default, inorder to stack them side by side, you need to either `float` them, or you need to use `display: inline-block;`

> Note: Your `id` values are invalid, you cannot start an `id` name with
>   a number.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FBa7u/)

```
#linkscontainer > div {
   float: left;
}
```

I've changed the dimensions to `25%` to `20%` to fit the content perfectly.

---

If you are going with `display: inline-block;` than you need to look out for the white space fix, if you are going with `float`, than don't forget to clear them using `clear: both;` property.

---

> Suggestion: Seems like you are making a navigation menu, so better you
>   use `ul` and `li` elements nested under `nav`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just changed the ID names to numbers when posting to here. It's not quite a navigation menu. I left several details out as I want to try as hard as I can to overcome problems myself, but this one, I just couldn't work out.

Your help is greatly appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: @user2586348 you welcome :) if it helped you, than you can mark this answer as correct by clicking on the tick beside my answer ...

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices, either [float the elements](http://jsfiddle.net/FtuKt/), or change them to [display inline](http://jsfiddle.net/FtuKt/1/), using:

`float:left;`
-or-
`display:inline;`
-or-
`display:inline-block;`

I'd recommend you have a look at [this article](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) about floating, and [this one](http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/) about inline elements (inline-block).

The two properties will both achieve the result you're after, but their behaviour and purpose varies- make sure you choose the most appropriate.

`div` elements are block level by default (they cause a 'break' in the vertical content) changing to make them display inline removes this break, so subsequent inline content is nested adjacently.

By setting float, you cause preceding/following content to flow around the element- in this case the content is also floated so it appears adjacently.

Comment: Dam it again you beat me... +1 -.-

Comment: @user2586348 in that case in order to stop the elements breaking to a new line you need to enclose them within a parent element with its width set to at least the minimum possible to cause the children to appear on one line.